# Чтение .dwg файлов в проекте на c++/c#

Tags: c++, autocad

Ребята, приветствую.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть .dwg файл с простыми 2D фигурами. Нужно каким-то образом написать программку, которая бы из этого файла получала периметр, площадь, длину и ширину (считаются максимальные значения фигуры). В идеале еще было бы и количество отверстий в фигуре посчитать, но это не совсем критично.
Облазил интернет, нашел там ссылку на https://github.com/sandyre/libopencad, но что-то у меня никак не выходит собрать все это счастье под винду (пытаюсь это сделать с помощью MSVC).
Может кто решал подобные проблемы. Поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае решением стала [CAD DLL](https://cadsofttools.ru/products/cad-dll/). Мне более чем подошла пробная/бесплатная версия, доступная для скачивания на сайте.